# C# How do I draw a line between two objects on a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, draw

I've been trying to draw a line between two objects for a long time now, but it still won't work.

My program is supposed to make two picture boxes (Already made, called PB1 and PB2) and connect them with a line on the form.

I have this:

```
public void DrawStuff(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        Point point1 = new Point(PB[0].Location.X, PB[0].Location.Y);
        Point point2 = new Point(PB[1].Location.X, PB[1].Location.Y);

        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2);
        CreateGraphics();
    }
```

But I can't call the function! Also, the Boxes are being created with a button, so it can't draw from the start, it has to do it after I push that button. If anyone has a working code, please let me know, I'm about to break down.

Comment: Is that draw event wired up?  I'm guessing not or else you would be seeing null exceptions on those PictureBoxes if they weren't created yet.  Use the OnPaint override instead.  Before accessing PB[0] and PB[1], make sure they exist.  You didn't give us the code for how you're creating those boxes.  Eliminate that CreateGraphics(); line — it's not doing anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not (read NEVER EVER) call `CreateGraphics()` explicitly. This is a crime against humanity, except for very rare situations.
2. Handle `Paint` event (or override `OnPaint()`) of your `Form`. Write your line drawing code in there.

Something like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPaint(e);

  using(var blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3))
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, PB[0].Location, PB[1].Location);
}
```

3. Whenever you need to refresh screen manually, call `this.Invalidate()`.

Comment: There's still something not working. It says that it can't change access modifiers when overriding protected members. And yes, I tried setting it to public.

Comment: @ExoSkull: Set it to protected as it is asking. My mistake too. Updated my code.

Comment: Ok, I got further, but this time now it crashes and doesn't even paint the other objects. A button would have to create the PictureBoxes first, so it tries to draw between the boxes that don't even exist yet...

Comment: @ExoSkull: You can easily fix this by declaring a global `bool` flag that is initially set to `false`. Then set it to `true` after creating your pictureboxes or whatever. In the `OnPaint()` event, check this flag before performing line drawing.